# NativeScript HelloWorld build.gradle Error

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, nativescript

Im stucking with this https://docs.nativescript.org/start/cli-basics NativeScript HelloWorld example.
When I run "tns doctor" everything seems to be fine and when I run "tns device" I can see my avd with a connected status.
But when I try to run my Project with "tns run android" I get a gradle Error. I have never worked with gradle before and Im really new to mobile development, so I dont know, what I can do to solve this problem. The message:

```
$ tns run android
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Skipping prepare.
Building project...
Gradle build...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file '/home/lars/Projects/app/Test/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.PluginCrashReporter
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1.
Stopping webpack watch

Im working on an Ubuntu 18.04 (Kubuntu), java version "1.8.0_201" and `tns info` gives this information:

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 5.2.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 5.2.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 5.2.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 5.2.0 version and is up to date.
```

I have tried to solve this problem for days and have no idea what I could do.

Comment: sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk ? Can you confirm your JAVA_HOME ? is it set properly?

Comment: Also try to re-install Android tools and set path again export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"

Comment: Make sure you have completed the Nativescript installation correctly, check your env. variables (are they pointing to the correct Android/Java directories), run tns doctor and make sure there are no conflicts, and try again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be useful but I noticed that new NativeScript version 6.0 has many problems with building the gradle. The error console is like the following error:

```
Build file 'D:\NativeScriptApps\<MyAppName>\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 254
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

I solved following these steps:

1.Install new version of Node.js if you did not downloading it from official site. You should have the message like this:

```
 Support for Node.js 8.0.0.0 is deprecated and will be removed in one of the next releases of NativeScript. Upgrade to the next LTS version.
```

2.Then update nativescript with CLI

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

3.Add the Android Platform 5.2.0 with CLI (changing the current, in case)

```
tns platform add android@5.2.0
```

4.Make a migration to the new version of {N} and dependencies (reporting the platform to the preview)

```
tns migrate
tns run android [ios]
```

5. If `tns run android` does not build then make android/ios with `tns update`

I hope everything will be fine.
Regards.